# Cannot send email to recipients outside local network on Exchange server with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, email, sendmail, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am developing an ASP.NET application using Web Forms and I'm stumbling on the (I think trivial) problem of sending an email from a Microsoft Exchange Server account.

I use the ExchangeService class (with the Microsoft EWS API) and the AutodiscoverUrl function to connect to the Exchange server.

This is my code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string from = "myemail@myexchangeserver.com";
   string to = "recipient@email.com";

   ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
   service.AutodiscoverUrl(from);

   EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
   message.Subject = "Email Subject";
   message.Body = TextBoxMessage.Text;
   message.ToRecipients.Add(to);
   message.Save();

   message.SendAndSaveCopy();
}
```

The problem is that I can only send emails to local email addresses i.e. from and to the Exchange server (only addresses from my company). Sending to an "external" emails such as gmail does not work, although the SendAndSaveCopy call does not throw any exception.

I should mention that this only works from my development server inside the company´s local network. If I disconnect from the local network, I can't connect to the Exchange server anymore and an exception is thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the exchange server is set up to relay from the ip address where the app/website is running.    I've run in to this problem before and that was generally the issue.

Comment: Also, you could check exchange server logs.

Comment: Most likely this isn't an issue with your code, but rather with the configuration of the Exchange server.  Most shops with good administrators put restrictions on what apps and what machines can relay emails, and there may even be some third party system blokcing the mails as they go out of your network.  This is good practice from a security standpoint because it limits the damage that can be done if a malicious program does get installed in the network and starts trying to send emails.  In short, you're likely having issues because of good security and need to talk to an admin.

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed at the reaction speed... How do I check the server is set to relay emails? Where do I find the exchange server logs?

Comment: Those questions are a better fit at ServerFault.com - That's the site for Administrators.  Are you in a one-man shop, or do you have an admin you can work with?

Comment: Thank You all. I've just received the emails I had sent 3 hours ago... some strange policy of my server I guess...I had to gain his trust...Anyway now the emails are sent immediately. Thanks anyway for the help, I'll know where to look now if anything happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my server does not accept AutodiscoverUrl and I had to manually set the credentialsto the emailaccount with 
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("userName", "password", "Domain");

Thank you for your comments, it really helped!